# Drawing rectangles on android canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw 5 squares of different side lengths but adjacent to each other. 
I want to draw the squares like this: http://s30.postimg.org/ajrtfabj5/squares.png

Assuming that the biggest square is of side length 5, side length of square smaller than 5 is 3, smaller than 3 is 2 and the rest two squares of side length 1 each, can anyone help me draw this on the android canvas ?

Also help me understand the arguments that are given in `drawRect(Left, Top, Right, Bottom, Paint);`

Comment: is it only this specific pattern that is required or will it need to be expandable for higher orders of the Fibonacci sequence ?

Comment: @Cob50nm yes, just 1,1,2,3 and 5 fibonacci numbers are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only want this to be for this specific pattern and not expandable then the following should work. Though it is unlikely that it will look right because it is unlikely that a screen will be 1:2 aspect ratio, so you might need to make your canvas a set size that conforms to a 1:2 aspect ratio.

```
int width =canvas.getWidth();
int height = canvas.getHeight();
float a = (height*3)/5;
flaot b = (height*2)/5;
float c = (width*3)/5;
float d = (width*4)/5;

//5x5 square
canvas.drawRect(0,a,width,height);
//3x3 square 
canvas.drawRect(0,0,a,c);
//2x2 square 
canvas.drawRect(c,0,width,b);
//first 1x1 square 
canvas.drawRect(d,b,width,a);
//second 1x1 square 
canvas.drawRect(c,b,d,a);
```

The variables a,b,c,d are explained in the following image [image: visual explanation of variables]

The parameters in `drawRect` are the coordinates of the corresponding edge of the rectangle in the canvas coordinate system. The canvas coordinate system has (0,0) in the top left of the screen. So if you wanted a triangle to fill the whole screen you would have `canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.get(width),canvas.getheight());`

This would put the left edge of the rectangle along 0 in the x axis, the top along 0 in the y axis, the right edge along the x axis at the width of the canvas and the bottom along the y axis at the height of the canvas.

Hope this helps.